# ASP.NET C# Open multiple modal popup inside loop, one by one

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, popup, modal-dialog

I have a `GridView` (`RadGridView` by Telerik) with a `CheckBox` column for multiple row selection. Each row represents a document and I need to be able to select multiple documents to apply them a digital signature.

Actually if only one document is selected, I open a new aspx page inside a popup and that page calls the DigitalSignature service (a web application listening on specific port) that open a Wacom screen wich waits for the signature on the Wacom tablet. When the user sign or close the window, the popup close and the `GridView` is updated.

I need to do this inside a foreach loop for every selected row.
The problem is that now I call `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` with unique name but they're opened all togheter at the same time but **I want to open one by one.**

*Possibly without using jQuery or 3rd party libraries.*

*I'm using .NET Framework v3.5.*

**Actual code:**

```
foreach (SelectedDocument selectedDoc in SelectedDocuments)
{
    Documento doc;

    try
    {
        // Open document
        doc = session.Load<Document>(Convert.ToInt64(selectedDoc.ID));

        if (doc != null)
        {
            // Get the file...

            // Do some stuff...

            // Set query string         
            string queryString = string.Format("Sign.aspx?fileNameToSign={0}&reader={1}&view={2}&docid={3}&userid={4}",
                                    pathQueryString, certificate, "0", selectedDoc.ID, UserId);

            string urlDownload = Page.ResolveClientUrl(string.Format("~/Path/To/Folder/{0}", queryString));

            string script = string.Format("loadDownload('{0}','_blank',600,600);", urlDownload);

            // Open Wacom window
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "DocID" + selectedDoc.ID, script, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set an on off check to see that the document has been signed, before the loop gets to the next document, it should wait (Use `await` to go on with the loop)

See example:

Start by creating a helper method to generate a task that will be completed when a button is clicked:

```
public static Task WhenClicked(this Button button)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        button.Click -= handler;
    };
    button.Click += handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

After that, you can easily wait until either 2 seconds (or more) have passed, or the button is clicked:

```
public  async void Bar()
{
    this.button.Focus();

    this.button.BackColor = Color.Green;

    await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(2000), button.WhenClicked());

    // now the loop continues and the button changes its color
    this.button.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the following NuGet packages, you can bring the power and simplicity of async/await to your older applications:

Microsoft Async

This package enables Visual Studio 2012 projects to use the new 'async' and 'await' keywords. This package also includes Task-based extension methods that allow using some of the existing asynchronous APIs with the new language keywords. Windows Phone Silverlight 8 projects can use this package to get access to async extension methods for the networking types.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I can't use 3rd party libraries (even from MS) because the project is a WebPart of a ASP.NET application and so I can't add other libraries to the project without approvation and testing.

Comment: Try maybe your bosses will give you approval, give it a shot and see what they say.